# Is it necessary to store images in memory to show on list view in android

Tags: android, image, listview, memory-management, drawable

I'm showing list with one `ImageView` on every row of list.

For that, I download images from net in another AsyncTask using `Drawable.createFromStream`
And store them as **Drawable** in `ArrayList` which I pass to my Adapter class extending BaseAdapter class.

But the images are taken with high-resolution camera, so may be of very large size.
And I'm getting `OutOfMemory` error.

So my questions :

1. What is more efficient, storing images as drawable or as bitmap or any other format?
2. Am I doing right, by storing all images in memory(in array list). i.e. I'm thinking, once I get a image, I will show it on ImageView and will not store in ArrayList.
3. is there any way, I can compress the images after download, so they will take less space in memory.

My total code is present [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135091/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-on-line-drawable-creat)

Answer (score 1):

There is pretty good library calling `AQuery`. YOu can use it and simple get all stuff like memory and file caching by writting only 2 line of code. So you even wouldn't need to prepare a drawable, you can call it directly from `Adapter.getView()` callback.

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(rowView);
aq.id(R.id.image).image(url, false, true);
```

Hope it help you!

From AQuery docs:

> Down Sampling (handling huge images)
>   We are loading a huge image from the network, but we only need the image to be bigger than 200 pixels wide. Passing in the target width of 200 will down sample the image to conserve memory.Aquery will only down sample with power of 2 (2,4,8...) for good image quality and 
>   efficiency.The resulting image width will be between 200 and 399 pixels
>
> `String imageUrl = "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5035/5802797131_a729dac808_b.jpg";
>
>   aq.id(R.id.image1).image(imageUrl, true, true, 200, 0);`

Comment: I see now, if you use it in `getView()` callback use `new AQuery(View v)` constructor where `v` is view of your row.

Comment: Thanks, now its working, now just I have to check with large no of images.

Comment: its working but with large no of images application getting hanged(not responding) :(

Comment: I use AndroidQuery too, and love it.  Suggested this same answer in another thread with similar question.

Comment: @Why and How about large images: i've updated my answer with AQuery doc. So read it carefully, it has lot of options http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't see any efficiency in storing high-density images into memory - it's totally not recommended to store large ammount of images as bitmaps in memory (good for you that you have a good device ;))
2. See p.1
3. Try downscaling the images to fit the device's needs - that's not a simple job though. Also, see [View.setTag(Object tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29)

**The adapter**

```
public class MyImageListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ImageLoadingNotifier {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyImageListAdapter() {
    inflater = LayoutInflater)HomeActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return listImageInfo.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listImageInfo.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }

    TextView tvName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
    final Button btnDelete = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);


    image.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.default_placeholder);//set default place-holder
    new GetDrawableFromUrl(listImageInfo.get(position), vi).execute();

    tvName.setText("Name: " + listImageInfo.get(position).getImage_name());
    tvTime.setText("Date: " + listImageInfo.get(position).getDate_created());

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
            positionOgBtnToDelete = position;
            Log.v("delete btn clicked", "delete btn no: " + position);
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Btn delete position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showAlertToConfirmDelete();
        }
    });
    return vi;
}

}
```

**The AsyncTask `GetDrawableFromUrl`**

```
public class GetDrawableFromUrl extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Drawable> {
public ImageInfo imageInfoObj;
private ImageView view;


GetDrawableFromUrl(ImageInfo imageInfo, ImageView view) {
    imageInfoObj = imageInfo;
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
protected Drawable doInBackground(Void... params) {
    try {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(((java.io.InputStream) new java.net.URL(imageInfoObj.getImageUrl()).getContent()), "src_name");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable != null) {
        //imageInfoObj.setImage(drawable);
        this.view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        //listImageInfo.add(imageInfoObj); //this one is called when the json is parsed
        showImagesInList(); //don't know what it does (??)
    }
}
```

}

**The JSON parsing**

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObjInner = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo();
                imageInfo.setImageUrl("http://www.dvimaytech.com/markphoto/" + jsonObjInner.getString("image"));

                //new GetDrawableFromUrl(imageInfo).execute(); //don't needed here

                imageInfo.setEmail(jsonObjInner.getString("emailid"));
                imageInfo.setImage_id(jsonObjInner.getString("image_id"));
                imageInfo.setImage_name(jsonObjInner.getString("image_name"));
                imageInfo.setAmount(jsonObjInner.getString("amount"));
                imageInfo.setImage_description(jsonObjInner.getString("image_description"));
                imageInfo.setDate_created(jsonObjInner.getString("date_created"));

                listImageInfo.add(imageInfo);
            }
```

And, the use of any kind of `List` of images becomes unnecesary :)

Instead of starting the async task (`GetDrawableFromUrl`) when parsing the json objects, you can start the task in `getView(...)` method. This way you will not be constrained to store the drawables into that `ArrayList`, since you'll be modifying the `ImageView` after the image was downloaded. And, by default, you can put a placeholder, until the image is downloaded (or in case there are some network errors).

This way the images will start downloading only when the `getView` method will be called for that specific item.

The bottom line is that each view from the `ListView` will keep a reference to it's specific drawable (that was set using `vi.setTag(image)`.

If this helps somehow, you know what to do ;)

Comment: Thanks 4 ur ans, but in ur sample example u have used img = listImageInfo.get(position).getImage(); i.e. storing images in listview. I'm also doing same now. And that's is my question, is it necessary to store(hold) images in listImageInfo?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new here, so not able to understand how setTag will help me here in this case

Comment: @WhyandHow I have modified my answer

Comment: please help me, I'm not getting how(exactly where) to start the AsyncTask in getView(). i.e. if I start it in if(img == null), then every time vi.setTag(img); will be executed before getting the image. And also after getting image in asynctask how to set it to that corresponding imageView

Comment: @WhyandHow here it is, try and see if it's ok

Answer (score 1):

Android documentation provides a very good example showing how to handle bitmaps in your android app. The example uses an on-disk and in-memory cache and loads the images in the background. By doing so, the main UI thread is not slowed down by loading the images.

[Loading Bitmaps effectively](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html)

In the example the images are loaded from picasa. It's easy, however, to adapt the example, so that pictures stored locally are used. You simply have to write your own ImageLoader extending from the 'ImageResizer':

```
public class ImageLoader extends ImageResizer {
    public ImageLoader(Context context, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
        super(context, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    }
    public ImageLoader(Context context, int imageSize) {
        super(context, imageSize);
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap processBitmap(Object data) {
        return decodeSampledBitmapFromFile((String)data, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    }
}
```

But to answer your question directly: it's ok to load images as Bitmaps. But you have to use a cache and weak references, so that the images can be garbage collected in case they are not visible on the screen. Caching them and using a background task for loading allows for a slick UI.

Comment: thanks 4 ur ans, but its all about accessing images locally, in my case I have to download each image from internet, and that's where I'm struggling, because then I have to store(hold) all images in my list which I'm passing to adapter.

Comment: If you have to download the images from the internet, then use the original "Loading Bitmaps effectively" example and the 'ImageFetcher' class.